# Are all finite sets of numbers decidable?

Tags: logic, computability

I'm reading Peter Smith's [Goedel's Theorems](https://www.logicmatters.net/igt/) and am embarrassingly suspicious of the claim (theorem 3.1) that all finite sets are effectively decidable. For example, the set $\{BB(7918)\}$ has one member (which I *think* is definable in arithmetic), the value of which is [independent of ZFC](https://www.scottaaronson.com/busybeaver.pdf).

The proof given in the book seems to rely on a finite set consisting of a concrete list of concrete numbers (rather than being defined by a predicate), and hence having a decidable characteristic function that simply checks the argument against all members of the set. What am I missing? If I'm not missing anything, what do we lose by realising that some finite sets *aren't* decidable?

Comment: Being decidable doesn’t mean that we know what the Turing program is, only that there is a Turing program. And there is a Turing program for every finite set. If we don’t know what set we are talking about, we can hardly know which program to use, but that is beside the point.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews so it's more complete to say that all finite sets _consisting of computable elements_ are decidable?

Comment: No. All finite sets are decidable.

Comment: @eapi It is useful here to distinguish between intension and extension. As you say, the value of $\textrm{BB}(7918)$ is independent of ZFC. But it is a finite number, and whatever finite number it is, its singleton set is a decidable set.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We have to distinguish between **sets** and **definitions of** sets.

A set is decidable *(or computable, or recursive - the subject has unfortunately redundant terminology!)* iff some Turing machine decides it. Every finite set is decidable since we can always "hard-code" a Turing machine to accept a given finite set: fixing $a_1,...,a_n$, just write a program which on input $k$ checks whether $k=a_1$, whether $k=a_2$,... , whether $k=a_n$, and outputs "YES" if the answer to one of these questions is YES and outputs "NO" otherwise.

However, some definitions of very simple sets appear computationally intractable. For example, for any sentence $\varphi$ let $$True_\varphi=\{x: (x=0\mbox{ and $\varphi$ is true})\mbox{ or } (x=1\mbox{ and $\varphi$ is false})\}.$$ Obviously $True_\varphi$ defines a decidable set (either $\{0\}$ or $\{1\}$), but we don't know which. This suggests the following notion (the terminology below is my own, I don't know if there's a more common one):

> Say that a definition $\delta$ of a set of natural numbers is **concrete** iff there is some Turing machine $M$ such that $\mathsf{ZFC}$ (say) proves that $M$ decides the set defined by $\delta$.

*(I'm being a bit vague here about what exactly I mean by "definition" - it doesn't really matter, but if you like we can take it to mean "formula in the language of set theory with one free variable which $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves only ever holds of natural numbers.")*

Before moving on, let me give a quick caveat:

### Not every decidable set has a concrete description!

The concretely-describable sets form a *proper subclass* of the decidable sets; every finite set is indeed concretely describable, though, so for now this is a reasonable thing to think about. *(See the end of this answer for more on this.)*

The point, then, is the following:

> Not every definition of a finite set need be concrete.

In particular, "The set containing exactly the $7918$th value of the Busy Beaver function" is **not** a concrete definition of a set; however, the set it defines is finite and does in fact have some concrete definition, we just don't know what it is.

---

OK, now let me get back to the point above about concrete describability vs. decidability.

Since we can search through $\mathsf{ZFC}$-proofs *(and assuming $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is sound)*, we can compute an enmeration $(M_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ of all Turing machines which $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves decide a set - that is, which $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves always halt on all inputs. But now we can diagonalize against these: the set $$D_{\mathsf{ZFC}}=\{i: M_i(i)=0\}$$ is decidable but has no concrete description.

*It's a good exercise to check why the above definition of $D_{\mathsf{ZFC}}$ is not in fact concrete! Also, note that $\mathsf{ZFC}$ isn't really important here - we can replace $\mathsf{ZFC}$ throughout with any other "appropriate" theory, like first-order Peano arithmetic.*

In particular, "The set of numbers decided by machine $M$" **is not concrete in general** ... since maybe $\mathsf{ZFC}$ doesn't prove that $M$ actually decides a set!

This is one of many situations in computability theory where **semidecidability** *(or computable enumerability, or recursive enumerability)* is a much tamer notion than decidability: while it's hard to tell whether a Turing machine decides a set, every Turing machine definitely *accepts* a set, so "is $\mathsf{ZFC}$-provably equivalent to a definition of the form 'the set of numbers accepted by $M$'" is a much better-behaved notion of concreteness than "is $\mathsf{ZFC}$-provably equivalent to a definition of the form 'the set of numbers decided by $M$.'"

(Incidentally, this winds up connecting with the topic of what functions a given theory - such as $\mathsf{ZFC}$ - can prove to be total. There's a vast literature on this, mostly in proof theory but spilling into computability theory and the study of models of arithmetic, but for a starting point see [Beklemishev, *Induction rules, reflection principles, and provably recursive functions*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168007296000450).)

Comment: (E.g. see [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0001870885901033) for a paper on the provably recursive functions of ZF-variants.)

Comment: "Not every decidable set has a concrete description" Perhaps I'm stuck on something silly, but didn't you rather mean "Not every description of a decidable set is concrete"? It seems to me that if a set S is decidable, then there is a TM m such that "m decides S" is a concrete description of S. Or not?

Comment: @JozefMikušinec Nope, the statement I made was correct! The point is that there are some decidable sets such that $\mathsf{ZFC}$ cannot prove the totality of any Turing machine which computes that set. (We're assuming here that $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is $\Pi_2$-sound.) This is easy to prove by diagonalization: assuming $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is $\Pi_2$-sound, the set of $i$ such that the $i$th $\mathsf{ZFC}$-provably-total Turing machine halts on input $i$ and outputs $0$ is decidable but not decidable by any $\mathsf{ZFC}$-provably-total machine.

Comment: And there's nothing special about $\mathsf{ZFC}$ here: if $T$ is any $\Pi_2$-sound theory then there is a decidable set $X$ such that there is no $T$-povably-total Turing machine computing $X$. I'll add some clarification on this point to the answer itself when I get time later.

Comment: In your definition of "concrete", do you mean to say "...$\mathsf{ZFC}$ (say) proves that $\delta$ defines the set decided by $M$."? Meaning, the proof itself refers to $\delta$? Otherwise I'm not seeing why "The set containing exactly the 7918th value of the Busy Beaver function" is not concrete, if it's a definition at all. It defines a singleton set $\{n\}$ of natural numbers, and there's certainly a Turning machine $M$ such that $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves $M$ decides $\{n\}$, right?

Comment: @blargoner I don't see the difference between what you've written and what I've written.  In particular, **yes**, the proof itself has to involve the definition $\delta$. (Maybe parentheses would have helped, a la "$\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves that ($M$ decides the set defined by $\delta$)"?)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Yes, parentheses or quotes would help. Otherwise it's not clear whether the set defined by $\delta$ might be referenced in a different way (not using $\delta$) in the proof. Similar to the intensional fallacy.